# Transfer from delegation fails

Tags: baking

Tried to send tezos from delegation account to my main account and keep getting this message:

```
Operation failed!

Id not known: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Can someone help?

Comment: you should edit your post with the exact command you tried that got that error.

Comment: in addition to the exact command, questions should provide all additional detail which might help someone provide you the correct answer. For example, what wallet were you using, what exactly were you doing, is the delegation account a KT? Also the stackexchange is for specific technical questions, for general wallet support you should go to the wallet support channels